Unable to override a leaflet method with include() method
I can't overload the following function of the leaflet BoxZoom class using include() method. I need to catch a key press while dragging. If I put a breakpoint in my code no stop happens. It seems the original function is always used.
L.Map.BoxZoom.include({
        _onPointerUp: function (evt) {
            if (evt.button !== 0) { return; }
            this._finish();
            if (!this._moved) { return; }
            this._clearDeferredResetState();
            this._resetStateTimeout = setTimeout(this._resetState.bind(this), 0);
            const bounds = new LatLngBounds(
                this._map.containerPointToLatLng(this._startPoint),
                this._map.containerPointToLatLng(this._point));

            if (evt.originalEvent.key == 'x') { //added code
                console.log("boxzoom + x");
            }
            else { // original zoom behavior
                this._map
                    .fitBounds(bounds)
                    .fire('boxzoomend', { boxZoomBounds: bounds });
            }
        }
    });

See Leaflet code source 
So I tried to overwrite it via include method like in the code above, but also tried to directly overwrite the prototype function, then after reading that the modification had to be made before initializing the map, I tried different places in my code :

inside / outside L.Map.addInitHook
inside / outside my plugin definition
inside a document.onload

... nothing works!
I already used include method to add new functions (without any problem), but it's the first time I uses it to change an existing method. The leaflet documentation is clear about this:

L.Class.include()
If a class is already defined, existing properties/methods can be redefined, or new ones can be added by using .include():

I don't understand what I'm missing.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

1: Create a separate JavaScript file (e.g., boxZoomOverride.js) and add your overridden _onPointerUp method
2: In your main JavaScript file or plugin, load the Leaflet.BoxZoom.js module and then your boxZoomOverride.js file

Sorry, tried that, no more result ...

What version of Leaflet are you using?

the latest: 1.9.4

Then go to your copy of 1.9.4's Map.BoxZoom.js and look for the _onPointerUp method. Then look at the release date of 1.9.4 and compare with https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/8757 .

Ok, got it to work. In fact the latest modifications of the BoxZoom class is related to changing all (on)Mouse(evt) to (on)Pointer(evt). So I used the latest sources to copy the _onPointerUp method that doesn't work. But changing it to _onMouseUp makes the override working !
As I get leaflet from this link https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js in my web page, it seems that the link gets a not updated code !
Thanks to IvanSanchez to put me on the right way.
